# Get values from mysql to xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, mysqli

I ran over a problem and need to fix it really fast.
I have a php code which gets the value from an xml file but i can't make a dynamic xml with database. My PHP version is 5.2 and my code for xml parsing is:

```
<?php
include("system/connect.php");
$q = mysqli_query($link, "select * from elements");
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement('link');

while(null !== ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))) {
   $xml->startElement("title");
   $xml->writeRaw($row['name']);
   $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("id");
   $xml->writeRaw($row['id']);
   $xml->endElement();

   $xml->startElement("img");
   $xml->writeRaw("images/elements/".$row['name'].".jpg");
   $xml->endElement();


} 
$xml->endElement();
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();
?>
```

What do I exactly want? I would like to parse chemical elements from database to xml, like

```
 <pages>
   <link>
     <title>Hydrogen</title>
     <id>1</id>
     <img>images/elements/Hydrogen.jpg</img>
  </link>
</pages>
```

The output now shows: [THIS](http://funchem.malamut.hu/new/links.php)

Comment: Kudos for using XMLWriter! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$xml->startElement('link');` should be inside of the loop, as well as `$xml->endElement();`

You also need to add `$xml->startElement('pages');` outside (with corresponding `endElement`)

Comment: the problem is that there are no tags, just values

Comment: what? there are tags! look at the source at your link. you can also add `header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');` to tell the browser that it is not html